# how to show only time-grid without TODO items in Org-Agenda?

Tags: org-agenda

I'd like to show only the time-grid and not show any tasks/todos below the time-grid.

I noticed a question similar to this [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/15309/25547), but the answer seemed to be about formatting the prefix of each item in the agenda view. That doesn't quite get at what I want to do.

One way I see to do this is to use `custom-agenda` and `skip-entry-if` to eliminate items where `'todo` matches my `todo-keywords`. Something like: `(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo ("TODO","WAIT","DONE","CNCL")`. This seems like overkill, but probably will work.

Is there a simpler approach?